# Underscore JS Update array of objects by key value pair

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

Say I have an array of objects like this:

```
$scope.colors = [
  {color:'Teal', id:5},
  {color:'Black', id:8},
  {color:'Red', id:9}
];
```

I want to do something like this

```
$scope.colors = _update(color='Yellow' where id=8);
```

How would you accomplish something like this in underscorejs? Or is Lodash or Typescript the best option for something like this?

The goal would be to have the new array be like this:

```
$scope.colors = [
  {color:'Teal', id:5},
  {color:'Yellow', id:8},
  {color:'Red', id:9}
];
```

I come from a PHP / MySQL background.

Answer (score 0):

You might not need underscore.js. `Array.map` will do it.

```js
var colors = [
  {color:'Teal', id:5},
  {color:'Black', id:8},
  {color:'Red', id:9}
];

colors.map(function(i){

    if(i.id == 8) {
        i.color= 'Yellow'; 
    }
    return i;

});

console.log(colors);
```

Comment: This method isn't working in angular for some reason, I have the object in a scope variable ($scope.colors), not sure why it wouldn't work in Angular but does in regular javascript.